# Spring Security for Hawt.io

Tags: java, spring-security, hawtio

I would like to configure *`Spring Security for Hawt.io`* with embedded tomcat. After custom login with (user and password) Hawt.io login is asking to authenticate.But Hawt.io authentication is disabled in code and in config. If I remove `MvcConfig` and `WebSecurityConfig` with `security.basic.enable= false` then without any authentication which works.But

> I want to authenticate with custom username and password which is
>   working after that Hawt.io is also asking the credentials though that
>   part is disabled.

Please help me to resolve this.

**application.properties**

```
hawtio.authenticationEnabled = false
management.security.enabled=false
security.basic.enable= true
security.ignored= /**
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**MvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/hawtio").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHawtio
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty(AuthenticationFilter.HAWTIO_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED, "false");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Update:**
Connect to dummy camel app like below login for again comes on giving credentials going to 404 error page.

[image]

Comment: i've tried your configuration and it works as expected, there is no hawt.io login form after spring login form.

Answer (score 2):

The following changes are required to make **hawtio** work with Spring Security and Spring Boot. You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-security-hawtio-example). *However, I wasn't able to update the username in hawtio menubar*.

#### Configure Spring Security

Configure Spring security for application in a standard way except for 
a few changes specfic to hawtio:

- Disable hawtio authentication,

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableHawtio
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.basaki"})
  public class Application {

      public static void main(String[] args) { 
          System.setProperty(AuthenticationFilter.
              HAWTIO_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED,"false");
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }
  }
  ```
- Disable Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) in your application.
- Make sure the logout request URL matches the `/hawtio/auth/logout/*`.
  This is the URL used by hawtio to invalidate a session.

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      ...

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
          .failureUrl("/login?error")
          .permitAll()
          .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(
          new AntPathRequestMatcher(
                  "/hawtio/auth/logout/*"))
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
          .and().csrf().disable();
      }
      ...
  }
  ```

#### Login Page

- Since you are using a form login, you will be needing a custom login page. In this example, a `login.html` is used.
- Configure the `/login` request to match view `login.html`

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class SpringMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
      }

      ...
  }
  ```

#### Updating hawtio's login.html

Once you log out from the hawtio page, it takes you to its own login page. Since it's a single page application with AngularJS, you need to replace this partial page with your own custom AngularJS based login page.

- In this example, a `login-hawtio.html` page is used.

  ```
  <div ng-controller="LoginPlugin.LoginController">
      <h1 style="color: #78ab46;">Sign in</h1>

      <form action="/login" method="post">
          <div>
              <label style="font-weight: 700; padding-right: 15px;
                  padding-left: 15px;">Username:
                  <input id="username" type="text" name="username"
                       placeholder="Username"/>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div>
              <label style="font-weight: 700; padding-right: 15px;
                  padding-left: 15px;">Password:
                  <input id="password" type="password" 
                      name="password" required
                      placeholder="Password"/>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  ```
- A controller to replace the existing hawtio login page.

  ```
  @Controller
  public class HawtioController {

      private ResourceLoader loader;

      @Autowired
      public HawtioController(ResourceLoader loader) {
          this.loader = loader;
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/hawtio/app/core/html/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET,
          produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
      public void getHawtioLoginHtml(HttpServletResponse response) {
          String location = "classpath:/templates/login-hawtio.html";
          try {
              String body = getResource(location);
              response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
              response.getWriter().write(body);
              response.getWriter().flush();
              response.getWriter().close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
          }
      }
      ...
  }
  ```

#### hawtio Login Plugin

- A custom hawtio plugin is needed to have your own AngularJS login controller, `LoginPlugin.LoginController`. It's used for redirecting to hawtio's home page after you are logged in from hawto's login page.

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class HawtioConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public HawtPlugin samplePlugin() {
          return new HawtPlugin("login-plugin",
              "/hawtio/plugins",
              "",
              new String[]{"plugin/js/login-plugin.js"});
      }
  }
  ```
- The `login-plugin.js` is located under `resources/app/webapp/plugin/js` folder.

  ```
  var LoginPlugin = (function(LoginPlugin) {

      LoginPlugin.pluginName = 'login-plugin';
      LoginPlugin.log = Logger.get('LoginPlugin');

      LoginPlugin.module = angular.module('login-plugin', ['hawtioCore'])
          .config(function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider.
              when('/home', {
                  templateUrl: '/hawtio/index.html'
              });
           });

      LoginPlugin.module.run(function(workspace, viewRegistry, layoutFull) {

          LoginPlugin.log.info(LoginPlugin.pluginName, " loaded");
          viewRegistry["login-plugin"] = layoutFull;
          workspace.topLevelTabs.push({
              id: "LoginPlugin",
              content: "Login Plugin",
              title: "Login plugin loaded dynamically",
              isValid: function(workspace) { return true; },
              href: function() { return "#/login-plugin"; },
              isActive: function(workspace) {
                  return workspace.isLinkActive("login-plugin"); }

          });
      });

      LoginPlugin.LoginController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
          var fullUrl = "/hawtio/index.html";
          $http({method: 'GET', url: fullUrl});
      };

      return LoginPlugin;

  })(LoginPlugin || {});

  hawtioPluginLoader.addModule(LoginPlugin.pluginName);
  ```

Comment: This is not working, when I try to connect to using (Connect to Remote server) though already session is established again it is asking credentials.If we give credentials then it is getting redirected to  http://localhost:8080/ and getting 404 error.This error is same as above posted one.

Comment: Is it possible for you check your project in GitHub? I will be able to help you to debug.

Comment: Thanks for reply, You can use same project u provided here https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-security-hawtio-example, Just u create one dummy camel project with jolokia in some other port no and try to connect from your hawtio it gives the error.Pls ping me if you need anything.

Comment: I will take a look and let you know.

Comment: With any camel keep below dependencies for jolokia functionality <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
   <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
   <artifactId>jolokia-client-java</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
   <artifactId>jolokia-spring</artifactId>
   <classifier>plugin</classifier>
   <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Please check the project on GitHub now.

Comment: It is also not working same authentication issue is there I will provide one project with same set up in Git.Thanks

Comment: I followed your solution in your github link. Will it be possible to set custom context path?